# Failing to start selenium webdriver with the error "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE"

Tags: java, selenium

I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1 version

Below is the code i tried

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setBrowserName(browserType);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
URL url = new URL("http://" + remoteIP + ":"+ port + "/wd/hub");            
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
```

And this is the error I am facing:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: check your dependencies, it seems that it starts yelling with that eror when there are dependencies conflicting. You might have different version of the same dependency.

Comment: Can you post more of the stacktrace? Is there a line number?